# apt package `netplan` vs `netplan.io`

Tags: apt, package-management, netplan

I see two packages in apt:

```
netplan.io - YAML network configuration abstraction for various backends

netplan - network server for `plan'
```

I presume `netplan.io` is the one for dealing with `/etc/netplan/foo.yaml` network configuration. Do I need to concern myself with `netplan` at all, or is this just a bad package name?

Comment: Check package via 'apt cache policy netplan' It may be that either one is dependency for another so they may be installed automatically so in that case no need to concern with it

Comment: Seems totally different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out.

[netplan](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/netplan) is the "network server for `plan'". [plan](https://www.bitrot.de/plan.html) being the calendar and day planner.

[netplan.io](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/netplan.io) is the YAML network configuration tool. This is 99.9% most likely the package people want.

The former has 1 bug, almost no activity, so I think it is just an issue of ambiguous naming.